# How shall I interpret the meaning of exhortation here in the paragraph?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"The later Stoics implemented that idea by stressing acts of kindness even for defeated enemies and slaves.  There were also **exhortations** to extend the characteristic Stoic love of self (oikeiōsis) in an ever-widening circle from self to family, to friends, and, at last, to humanity as a whole."

I searched for the meaning of exhortation which was "an address or communication emphatically urging someone to do something."  , which if I paraphrase is to force people to do something, but I am not able to comprehend the lines given with this defintion.

Full article - https://www.britannica.com/topic/cosmopolitanism-philosophy

Comment: It doesn't mean to force someone to do something. It means too encourage someone strongly to do something. There is a difference. Look up *exhort*.

Comment: "Urging" and "forcing" are certainly not the same thing.

Comment: it says emphatically urging , and emphatic means in a forceful way https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/emphatically